# Apparently simple Wikidata SPARQL filter query is slow

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Absolute Wikidata and SPARQL beginner here. I am trying to find out the Q code of a particular female name, say Jennifer. I can get it with a query like this:

```
SELECT ?name WHERE {
  ?name wdt:P31 wd:Q11879590.
  ?name rdfs:label ?label.
  FILTER((STR(?label)) = "Jennifer")
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
LIMIT 1
```

That is, I look up entities that are instance of "female given name" and then filter to those with "Jennifer" in the label. It works, but it takes 5 s or more.

If I omit the LIMIT 1 I get many instances of the same results, which signals to me that I am doing something stupid.

Bottom line, is there an efficient way to look up the Q code for a "female given name"?

Comment: `SELECT * { ?name wdt:P31 wd:Q11879590 ; wdt:P1705 "Jennifer"@mul }`

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks again! You really have to get to know those properties...

Comment: 5 s is OK, 30 s is slow. ~1s + some luck: https://pastebin.com/raw/eLj9zV9c